# How to design a discussion tab on a facebook page?

Tags: facebook

We have a facebook page.In which we want to design Discussion Tab.We Want to design each topic view.one more question we have Can we restrict users to create a new topic?we want only admin can create a discussion.I have attached a image we want each image in separate discussion topic.for ex if we have 2 topic 1st->net & 2nd->php so we want to design both discussion topic page. I have tried a lot but not getting exact answer,Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with discussion tab, it is not allowed by facebook, alternatively what you can do is remove this default facebook discussion tab form the page and create you own using facebook API.

Comment: Are you sure about it?can i have any url from where we can see alternative of this.Thanks

Comment: Yes I am 110% sure about it. Any customization you want on your page can be done in a custom tab like this one http://www.facebook.com/socialcubix?v=app_172356966111778 basically its a facebook application that is added to that page or can be static FBML(Banned by facebook)